# textareaで受け取ったデータの改行

Tags: php, html

textareaのデータをPOSTで受け取り、

```
$_POST["textarea"]
```

を使って、テキストエリアで入力された改行に`<br>`を入れたい場合、どのような処理が必要でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

テキストエリアの内容を次のように data で受け取ったとします。

```
$data = $_POST["textarea"]
```

次の関数を使うことで、テキストエリアの改行は`<br>`に変換されます。

```
nl2br()
```

なので、以下のようにすると、テキストエリアに入力された内容は、改行した状態で出力されます。

```
<?php
  echo nl2br($data);
?>
```

参考記事：
http://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.nl2br.php

※特殊文字のエスケープ処理はちゃんと行ってくださいね

Comment: ＞特殊文字のエスケープ処理はちゃんと行ってくださいね
以下の関数を使えば宜しいでしょうか？
htmlspecialchars()

Comment: まずはそれで良いと思います。エスケープしたときとしないときで、HTMLタグをテキストエリアへ入力したときの結果の違いを確認すると良いかと存じます。